# 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, dataframe

error

```
'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

code fragment

```
for index, row in dataframe_output.iterrows():
    print(index)
    molecule = index.pop()
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Pop is a function of a list. So either your 'row' could be a list and you want to pop that. Or 'dataframe_output'.

Comment: i want to pop out one by one row from the dataframe output

Comment: Perhaps `row.pop()` ?